# Having trouble installing Mcrypt for a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, mcrypt

I'm a noob with terminals and I'm trying to start learning Laravel. However, every time I run

`composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname --prefer-dist`

I get a error saying Mcrypt PHP extension required. I have been searching around for two days now, I tried mcrypt installers, Homebrew, MAMP and I still get the same error.

My PHP version is 5.4.30, and I'm on OS X. I tried upgrading to 5.5 but it still says 5.4.30. Does anyone know what is going wrong or what a possible fix is?

Comment: solved! i followed this tutorial and it works now http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through this yesterday. This guide helped me tremendously - http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/.

Answer (score 1):

Because Mcrypt is an extension which is not shipped within the PHP package. You need to install it on your server with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

And restart the webserver to let it kick in.

Comment: i get "sudo: apt-get: command not found"
I just reformatted my computer a few hours ago to use Mavericks, I downloaded iterm2, installed homebrew, installed wget, then I installed oh-my-zsh, and thats it. if that helps.

Comment: @xslibx, yes, `apt-get` is for Linux. Homebrew or Macports for OS X is just fine.